# Get parameters of a Json

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to acces the params of a Json Object and get in trouble when there is an array inside the Json.

```
Example:
{
    "data":{
        "data_type": "getUsername",
        "user":"bla"
    }
}

$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data_back = json_decode($data);
$userName = $data_back->data->user;
echo $userName;
```

this works fine. But if there is an array used an I change

```
$data_back = json_decode($data); to $data_back = json_decode($data,true);
```

I'm not able to access any data.

```
Example:
{
    "data":{
        "data_type": "getUsername",
        "user":[{
                    "username":"a",
                    "username":"b"
                }]
    }
}
```

Which type of `json_decode()` should I use if there could be an array or not?

Comment: try `json_decode($data,true);`

Comment: I allready tryed it. How can I echo the params within the Json array?

Comment: `print_r` or `var_dump` should do it.

Comment: You're missing the indexes on `user`.

Comment: Oh yeah that makes more sense...

You made an array with a single cell of json with same key!
Careful with these things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overwriting the same property in the JSON:

```
{
    "data":{
        "data_type": "getUsername",
        "user":[{ // array containing 1 object
                    "username":"a", // with 2 properties with the same name
                    "username":"b"
                }]
    }
}
```

What you WANNA do is:

```
{
    "data":{
        "data_type": "getUsername",
        "user":[
            { "username":"a"} ,
            { "username":"b"}
        ]
    }
}
```

Then you would be able to access it:

```
echo $data_back->data->user[0]->username; // a
echo $data_back->data->user[1]->username; // b
```

You don't need to pass `true` to `json_decode`, because you can still access this as an object. The difference between true and false as the 2nd argument is, example:

```
$json = '{"name":"Daniel"}';
$data1 = json_decode($json);
$data2 = json_decode($json, true);

var_dump($data1);
var_dump($data2);

// First one RETURNS an object:
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(6) "Daniel"
}

// Second one returns an ARRAY:
array(1) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(6) "Daniel"
}
```

But the input is the same.